# EOFException RandomAccesFile read

Tags: java

implementing reading and writing objects in a file access depending on the returned hash, I came across an error EOFException when reading and writing chain.

My method of writing is this.

```
private void escribirCadena( RandomAccessFile archivo, String cadena )throws IOException
{
   StringBuffer bufer = null;
   if ( cadena != null )bufer = new StringBuffer( cadena );

   bufer.setLength( 6 );
   archivo.writeChars( bufer.toString() );
}
```

my reading method for registration is

```
public Persona obtenerRegistro( int i ) throws IOException{
   if(i >= 0 && i < NumeroRegistros) {
        archivo.seek(i * Persona.TAMANIO);
        return new Persona(leerCadena(archivo),leerCadena(archivo));
       //return leerCadena(archivo);
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nNúmero de registro fuera de límites.");
        return null;
    }
 }


private String leerCadena( RandomAccessFile archivo ) throws IOException
{
    char nombre[] = new char[6], temp;
   for ( int cuenta = 0; cuenta < nombre.length; cuenta++ ) {
   temp = archivo.readChar();
   nombre[ cuenta ] = temp;
   }

   return new String( nombre ).replace( '\0', ' ' );
}
```

I work with additional data objects with two attributes of type String
I mark error for the method `leerCadena`  , line `temp = archivo.readChar();`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it because you're out of the number of persons? :

```
if(i >= 0 && i <= NumeroRegistros) {
```

Should be probably:

```
if(i >= 0 && i < NumeroRegistros) {
```

Other than that there are few other problems. Like the StringBuffer being set to length 10 but just before write it's set to 30.

Comment: modify what you recommended, the error still dating. Modify the code above

Comment: So can you check the file is big enough to have numeroRegistros entries? Did you really store the entries?

Comment: @zbynek-vyskovsky-kvr000  probe only insert records and makes normal, but when I want to get data from a file position get the error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are reading the file beyond it's capacity. You should only read until the End Of File (EOF) is reached. Check the JavaDocs for the class you are using to read the file. It will tell you about 'End Of File'.

Comment: where in me I can be mistaken?